# How can I set a radio button in a grid to "checked"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a 3 Radio Buttons in a grid

```
      <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xrbtCommodityDescription"
                                                FieldName="CommodityDescription"
                                                Header="Commodity Description"
                                                AllowEditing="True"
                                                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"
                                                Width="145" MinWidth="60">
                                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <RadioButton x:Name="xrbtCommodityDescription" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}"  
                                                         Checked="RadioButton_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </dxg:GridColumn>
                                <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xrbtCommoditySpanish"
                                                FieldName="CommoditySpanish"
                                                Header="Commodity Description Spanish"
                                                AllowEditing="True"

                                                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"
                                                Width="190" MinWidth="60">
                                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <RadioButton x:Name="xrbtCommoditySpanish" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                                                         Checked="RadioButton_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </dxg:GridColumn>
                                <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="xrbtNone"    
                                                FieldName="None"
                                                Header="Item Description"
                                                AllowEditing="True"
                                                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource bold}"
                                                Width="105" MinWidth="40">
                                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <RadioButton x:Name="xrbtNone" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                                                         Checked="RadioButton_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </dxg:GridColumn>
```

I want 'xrbtNone' to be checked if the other two are false, but since I don't have 'xrbtNone' saving to the database, when I reopen the interface it's unselected.

How can I set it to checked if the other two are unselected?

I tried creating a property but it didn't work, this is my current code for my radiobuttons

```
  private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var selectedItem = xgrdCustFLDocType.SelectedItem as CustomerFLDocType;
            RadioButton RBT = sender as RadioButton;

            if ((Boolean)RBT.IsChecked && RBT.Name == "xrbtCommodityDescription")
            {
                selectedItem.CommodityDescription = true;
                selectedItem.CommoditySpanish = false;
                selectedItem.None = false;                  
            }

            if ((Boolean)RBT.IsChecked && RBT.Name == "xrbtCommoditySpanish")
            {
                selectedItem.CommoditySpanish = true;
                selectedItem.CommodityDescription = false;
                selectedItem.None = false;                    
            }

            if ((Boolean)RBT.IsChecked && RBT.Name == "xrbtNone")
            {
                selectedItem.CommoditySpanish = false;
                selectedItem.CommodityDescription = false;
                selectedItem.None = true;                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ITTaskList.ErrorHandler("Unable To Select Radio Button.", ex, this.Name);
        }
        finally
        {                
            EnableButtons();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by setting up my property like this:

So since my 'ischecked' property is set to binding, this conditional statement sets the bool to a value and returns the property allowing the button to function normally without me having to add a field in the database.

private static readonly PropertyInfo _NoneProperty = RegisterProperty(p => p.None, "None");

```
    public System.Boolean None
    {
        get
        {
            if (!CommodityDescription && !CommoditySpanish)
            {
                None= true;
            } 

            else
            {
                None= false;
            }
            return GetProperty(_NoneProperty); 
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(_NoneProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully undertstood what you wanted to do, but you want the radio button "xrbtNone" to be checked if the other 2 buttons aren't checked?

```
private void CheckButtonIfUnchecked()
{
   if (radioButton1.Checked = false && radioButton2.Checked = false)
   {
      xrbtNone.PerformClick();
   }
}
```

This should work.

**Short explanation:**

*If the 2 radio buttons (you'll need to change the names) are unchecked, it'l the "xrbtNone" button. Not hard to understand. Hopefully this helps you :)*

Comment: Since my radio button is in a grid i cannot check if the specific button is checked or check a specific button, that would work if it were not in a grid.

Comment: Ah, gridview. Missed that. Well, not sure about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in two parts. First, you want to give all your radio buttons the GroupName property, as explained at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The syntax should be something like:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="xrbtCommoditySpanish" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}" 
Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Groupname="LanguageRadioButtons" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This will ensure that only one of the buttons can be checked, and it should work regardless of the gridview. If not, then take a look at Step 3 of the tutorial at https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs

Second, you can designate that xrbtNone is checked from the start by including "xrbtNone.Checked = true;" in your instantiation code. This will fire the Checked event, but you can prevent that by deactivating the radio buttons before checking it and re-activate them afterwards, if you do not wish to fire that event.

Comment: I can't set it to GroupName because in a GridView if I set it to a GroupName and there is multiple rows then it will unselect all the other buttons in all other rows. But ill try to see if setting it to default true will help.

Comment: You should be able to set different GroupNames for the different sets of buttons. So, you may have LanguageGroup, TimeZoneGroup, EthnicityGroup, etc. If you do that, then I think the changes to the LanguageGroup buttons will not affect any of the other button groups. Hopefully this wouldn't force you to create many groups of buttons that you did not want to group.

Comment: The problem is that when i add a new row to the grid view and i select one of the three buttons the buttons in the first row become unselected since they are grouped, so the only way i can control them is through the binding.